# What is the difference between ::class and ::class.java in Kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin, reflection

In Java, we write `.class` (for example: `String.class`) to get information about the given class. In Kotlin you can write `::class` or `::class.java`. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 57):

By using `::class`, you get an instance of [KClass](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/). It is Kotlin Reflection API, that can handle Kotlin features like properties, data classes, etc.

By using `::class.java`, you get an instance of Class. It is Java Reflection API, that interops with any Java reflection code, but can't work with some Kotlin features.

Comment: Why can't the compiler handle this for us? Stupid me spent 30min searching for this...

Answer (score 15):

First you need to understand about **Reflection**. According to the docs:

> Reflection is a set of language and library features that allows for introspecting the structure of your own program at runtime.

In simple words, it gives you the ability to get the code you have written i.e., the class name you have defined, the function name you have defined, etc. Everything you have written, you can access all these at runtime using `Reflection`.

`::class` and `::class.java` are basic features of Reflection.

`::class` gives you a `KClass<T>` reference and `::class.java` gives you `Class<T>` reference.
Example,

```
val a = MyClass::class
```

can be interpreted as

```
val a = KClass<MyClass>()
```

*Note: Above code is not syntactically correct, because `KClass` is an interface and interfaces cannot be instantiated. It is just to give you an idea.*

A `Class<T>` class gives you information about the metadata of the T class like interfaces it is implementing, its functions' names, its package name, etc.

`KClass` is similar to `Class` but it gives information about some more properties(Kotlin related properties) than `Class`. All the information a `KClass<T>` reference can give you about the T class are listed here https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/#properties

Answer (score 13):

According to the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references), when we create an object using any class type as below the reference type will be type of KClass.

```
val c = MyClass::class  // reference type of KClass
```

Kotlin class reference is not the same as a Java class reference. To get a Java class reference, use the .java property on a KClass instance.

```
val c = MyClass::class.java  // reference type of Class Java
```