# Error "Name expected" when trying to deserialize

Tags: kotlin, rest-assured

I am new to Rest Assured and I don't understand what kind of name is it expected. I am trying to deserialize response

Here is a test itself

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.given
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder
import io.restassured.http.ContentType
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification
import org.junit.Test
import pojos.UserData


class RestTest {
    private var requestSpec: RequestSpecification = RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setBaseUri("https://reqres.in")
        .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .setBasePath("/api/users/")
        .addQueryParam("page", 2)
        .build()

    @Test
    fun getUsers() {
            var response =
                given().spec(requestSpec)
                    .`when`().get()
                    .then().extract().body().`as`(UserData.class)
    }}
```

And here is pojo class

```
package pojos
import lombok.Builder
import lombok.Data

@Data
@Builder

class UserData {
    var id: Int = 0
    var email: String? = null
    var first_name: String? = null
    var last_name: String? = null
    var avatar: String? = null

}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Here is the picture with an error]

Comment: Can you try using `::class.java`? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#class-references https://stackoverflow.com/q/59781916/4161471

Comment: You might like to try out the [Kotlin Extension Module](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Kotlin#kotlin-extension-module). It should make using Rest Assured from Kotlin more convenient.

Comment: I already have Kotlin extension dependency in pom file

Comment: ::class.java  works! Thanks!